# Testing for duplicated character strings across the rows of a matrix

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have this data:

```
edge_list <- matrix(data = c("test1", "test", "test", "test1", "stuff",
"not_related"), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

     [,1]    [,2]         
[1,] "test1" "test"       
[2,] "test" "test1"       
[3,] "stuff" "not_related"
```

Note here that both rows 1 and 2 contain `test` and `test`. While they appear in different orders, these two rows are still considered to be duplicates for the purposes of this question.

Now I want to find which rows are duplicates of which. I tried:

```
lapply(edge_list, duplicated)
```

and

```
duplicated(edge_list)
```

none of which can find the duplicated rows.

How can I just extract the first two rows which are duplicates of each other?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort each row and then use `duplicated`:

```
duplicated(t(apply(edge_list, 1, sort)))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```